rfc2445, gap 2 days between any 2 events
I'm creating a calendar application which should be complaint with [rfc-2445] (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) specification. is there a way to create these events with gap of X days between them.

No idea what you're asking, but RFC 2445 is deprecated and you want RFC 5545
